# Selecting all columns with NOT NULL values for given row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with id, A, B, C, D columns. Each row has a unique NOT NULL values of A, B, C, D columns: for the row with id=1 it is: A,C,D;  for the row with id = 2 it is: B,C, and so on. I need help in writing SQL script that will return a list of columns with NOT NULL values for each given row. Something like:

```
SELECT NOT_NULL_Columns FROM table WHERE id=1;
```

The expected result is a table with only one row, names of columns and corresponding (not null) values

Comment: do you just want the column names or the actual values?

Comment: Actually both of them.  The expected result is a table with only one row, names of columns and corresponding values

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for a SQL query to return a variable number of columns, so I'll assume you want the **names** of the columns that have non-null values.

You can do:

```
select *,
  case when a is not null then 'A ' else '' end ||
  case when b is not null then 'B ' else '' end ||
  case when c is not null then 'C ' else '' end ||
  case when d is not null then 'D ' else '' end as not_null_columns
from t
```

Result:

```
 id  a     b     c  d     not_null_columns 
 --- ----- ----- -- ----- ---------------- 
 1   7     null  7  7     A C D            
 2   null  7     7  null  B C              
 3   null  7     7  7     B C D
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cP4JA3RhPp8h2VJ5g9mNX4/0).

Now, if you wanted the non-null **values** that would be a different story. Since SQL cannot produce a variable number of columns, the solution could go in the direction of assembling all non-null values into a structure such as an array, an XML doc, a JSON doc, or even a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the row to a JSON value and remove all keys (=columns) with NULL values:

```
select jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t) - 'id')
from the_table t
where id = 1;
```